# Overloading the = Operator in a Class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've built a quaternion class and want to know if I should overload the = operator. Is there any greater benefit to overloading this? What are the detriments to not overloading it?

If I do overload it it will be done like this:

```
if (this != &Input) 
{
        w = Input.w;
        x = Input.x;
        y = Input.y;
        z = Input.z;
        Normalise();
        CalculateMatrix();
}
return *this;
```

Comment: If you don't overload it, the compiler will generate one that copy-assigns each member individually.  If you aren't holding any raw pointers to allocated memory, that's probably exactly what you want.  You generally need to overload copy-assignment (and copy-constructor) only if your destructor will do something bad if executed twice (once on each of two clones)

Comment: @BenVoigt seems he does other things besides copying

Comment: @spock: seems his manual implementation copies less than the whole object, and recalculates values that probably already exist in the source object.

Comment: What does `CalculateMatrix` do? Can you show your whole class definition?

Comment: CalculateMatrix generates the values needed for the quaternion's matrix. I figured out that I should create the overload. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've built a quaternion class and want to know if I should overload
>   the = operator. Is there any greater benefit to overloading this? What
>   are the detriments to not overloading it?

You haven't shown your class definition. Without this one would not be able to comment. Typically, if your class does (not) have ownership of any indirect members (pointers), then the default generated copy constructor / assignment operator is adequate. These defaults performs memberwise copy (copies every member) by value. If one of your members happen to be a pointer, this would be copied by value too (and the rhs/source of the assignment would still contain the original pointer). The problem arises during first deletion of the either source/destination of assignment, when one of the objects delete the "owned" memory, whilst the other is still holding onto it (via indirect member).